# Link that pass parameters to servlet

Tags: java

I hava a web page with a link like something like `<a href=myPage/MyServlet&param=12>...` and `MyServlet` is a servlet deployed in Apache-Tomcat, but when I click that link I get a error 404. So can't I pass parameters to my srevlet? I need to configurate something more in apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want

```
<a href=myPage/MyServlet?param=12>...
                        ^  ("?" instead of "&" as you posted in your question)
```

You get a 404 because the page `myPage/MyServlet&param=12` does not exist.

The syntax of a link is `www.example.com?param1=val1&param2=val2&param3=val3`, that is, `?` separates the query from the URL, and the `&` separates parameter/value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

404 means page not found, so the URL you are clicking links to a page that does not exist.

What is the URL of the page with the link on it? What is the (full) URL of the page you want to link to?